# Test the convergence of the following series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find the limit of the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}+x} = $,$x\geq0$

So I used Ratio test as follows:

$u_n=\frac{1}{2^n+x}$

$u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+x}$

$\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}=\frac{2^{n+1}+x}{2^n+x}$,

Taking limits as n tends to infinity, I got :

$lim\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}=2>1$

So given series is convergent. But in my textbook, the answer given is: convergent if $x=0$ and divergent if $x$ is not equal to 0. I can see why it is convergent if $x$ equals 0, but why is it divergent if $x$ not equal to 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As presented it is obviously convergent.  Either the book is wrong or your description is wrong.  The Only divergent possibility is $x=-2^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Hmm changing it  to $2^n+x^n$ or $(2+x)^n$ would not change it to divergent for all $x\neq 0$, so even a typo on denominator is suspicious. Another possibility is $(\frac 1{2^n}+x)$ but then what is the interest of the exercise, just split the series ?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the answer. Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textbook answer is definitely wrong. Actually you can use comparison test:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{2^{n}+x}\leq\dfrac{1}{2^{n}},~~~~x\geq 0
\end{align*}
and $\sum 2^{-n}<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did suspect that answer is wrong, but wanted to confirm. Thanks again!